# sed filter colon separated list

Tags: regex, bash, sed

i have the following list generated with openssl

```
openssl ciphers 'ALL:eNULL'
```

Result:

```
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:SRP-DSS-AES-256-CBC-SHA:SRP-RSA-AES-256-CBC-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-HA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA:DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA256-SHA:AECDH-AES256-SHA:SRP-AES-256-CBC-SHA:ADH-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ADH-AES256-SHA256:ADH-AES256-SHA:ADH-CAMELLIA256-SHA:ECDH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-HA384:ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES256-SHA256:AES256-SHA:CAMELLIA256-SHA:PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:SRP-DSS-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA:SRP-RSA-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:AECDH-DES-CBC3-SHA:SRP-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA:ADH-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDH-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:DES-CBC3-MD5:PSK-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:SRP-DSS-AES-128-CBC-SHA:SRP-RSA-AES-128-CBC-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-SEED-SHA:DHE-DSS-SEED-SHA:DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA:DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA128-SHA:AECDH-AES128-SHA:SRP-AES-128-CBC-SHA:ADH-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ADH-AES128-SHA256:ADH-AES128-SHA:ADH-SEED-SHA:ADH-CAMELLIA128-SHA:ECDH-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES128-SHA:SEED-SHA:CAMELLIA128-SHA:IDEA-CBC-SHA:IDEA-CBC-MD5:RC2-CBC-MD5:PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-RC4-SHA:AECDH-RC4-SHA:ADH-RC4-MD5:ECDH-RSA-RC4-SHA:ECDH-ECDSA-RC4-SHA:RC4-SHA:RC4-MD5
:RC4-MD5:PSK-RC4-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC-SHA:EDH-DSS-DES-CBC-SHA:ADH-DES-CBC-SHA:DES-CBC-SHA:DES-CBC-MD5:EXP-EDH-RSA-DES-CBC-SHA:EXP-EDH-DSS-DES-CBC-SHA:EXP-ADH-DES-CBC-SHA:EXP-DES-CBC-SHA:EXP-RC2-CBC-MD5:EXP-RC2-CBC-MD5:EXP-ADH-RC4-MD5:EXP-RC4-MD5:EXP-RC4-MD5:ECDHE-RSA-NULL-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-NULL-SHA:AECDH-NULL-SHA:ECDH-RSA-NULL-SHA:ECDH-ECDSA-NULL-SHA:NULL-SHA256:NULL-SHA:NULL-MD5
```

I want to extract all entries that contain certain words, but I want to do it with sed and ONE regular expression. I know I can also do it with:

```
openssl ciphers 'ALL:eNULL' | tr ":" "\n" | grep MYWORD |tr "\n" ":"
```

but I have a feeling there is a simpler way

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: same list as above but missing all entries with WORD. example: word = rc4 then i dont wanna see "edh-dss-cgc-sha" cause it doesnt contain rc4

Comment: Show the expected output with an example

Comment: missing or containing MYWORD?

Comment: rather than describing the output please write it verbatim

Comment: openssl ciphers 'ALL:eNULL' | SOME SED EXPRESSION WITH PARAM "RC4"
output: ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-RC4-SHA:AECDH-RC4-SHA:ADH-RC4-MD5:ECDH-RSA-RC4-SHA:ECDH-ECDSA-RC4-SHA:RC4-SHA:RC4-MD5:RC4-MD5:PSK-RC4-SHA:EXP-ADH-RC4-MD5:EXP-RC4-MD5:EXP-RC4-MD5:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

awk is better suited for this job:

```
openssl ciphers 'ALL:eNULL' | awk -v w=RC4 '!($0~w)' RS=':' ORS=':'
```

To get all the words with searched string use:

```
openssl ciphers 'ALL:eNULL' | awk -v w=RC4 '($0~w)' RS=':' ORS=':'
```

- `RS=':'` makes record separator as `:` in input string making each record appear in separate record for awk
- `!($0~w)` finds all records that don't match variable `w` which is set in `-v` option
- `ORS=':'` makes output record separator as `:`

Comment: thx a lot, do you mind explaining it? i am not at all familiar with awk

Comment: I added explanation in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this gives what you need(WORD here here is RSA):

```
openssl ciphers 'ALL:eNULL' |perl -pe 's/:/\n/g'| grep RSA | perl -lne 'push @a,$_;END{print join ":",@a}'
```